# Accidentally moved files into another file instead of a folder

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, script

I used a simple python script to clean up my desktop, using the code

```
import glob
import shutil
import os

dir = os.getcwd()

for data in glob.glob(dir + "\*.exe"):
    shutil.move(data,dir + "\Executables_")

for data in glob.glob(dir + "\*.msi"):
    shutil.move(data,dir + "\Set-Up Folder_")

for data in glob.glob(dir + "\*.zip"):
    shutil.move(data,dir + "\Zips_")

for data in glob.glob(dir + "\*.rar"):
    shutil.move(data,dir + "\Zips_")

for data in glob.glob(dir + "\*.jpg"):
    shutil.move(data,dir + "\Pictures_")

for data in glob.glob(dir + "\*.png"):
    shutil.move(data,dir + "\Pictures_")

for data in glob.glob(dir + "\*.docx"):
    shutil.move(data,dir + "\Documents_")
```

Unfortunately I forgot to make the folders that I moved files into, and before I figured out something was wrong I moved 260MB worth of data into another file called "Executables_". Since the file isn't empty, is there a way to recover this data by somehow changing the file in question into a directory?
Should mention that this is on a Windows 10 PC.

Comment: If you had a backup solution in place, like Google Backup and Sync, or Windows Shadow Copy, then you might be able to get your data back.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry Oskar,  I think you are out of luck here.

Also.. look at your command.. "Executables_" only represents the LAST .exe it acted on, not all of them.

Anyone that has been programming a while has done this to themselves many times.  I deleted my ENTIRE Windows 98 registry when trying to write my first recursive function.

Good luck.